# Windows 7, Network and Sharing center shows no network, but computer is connected and browsing

Tags: windows-7, networking

Windows 7 Home Premium 32Bit

The Network and Sharing center shows no network connection. Ethernet cable is plugged in, web browsing functions perfectly.

I'm attempting an Anytime Upgrade but it does not attempt to connect if the Network and Sharing center thinks it is not connected.

Only the Network and Sharing center shows something wrong. All network tests pass with flying colors.

IPv6 is disabled.

Have tested each adapter while the other(s) were disabled and show no change.

No warning of Limited Network Access.

IPCONFIG with Wireless adapter disabled:

```
C:\Users\admin>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ITA00000589
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : CM.local

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : CM.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 64-31-50-10-01-33
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.238(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, December 14, 2011 10:31:42 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, December 16, 2011 11:55:20 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.250
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.CM.local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : CM.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: I have also disabled IPv6 on both adapters.

Comment: Have also made sure to test each adapter with the other one disabled.  No difference.

Comment: I have no warnings of "Limited Network Access"

Comment: Can you edit your question and post an `ipconfig`?  If there are multiple adapters, then you may have a gateway or routing issue.

Comment: I don't see how it could be gateway or routing issues since I have no problem using the network.  It is only the Network and Sharing Center that isn't working correctly.

Comment: So this is a Home OS on a non-home network?  Or does your home network really have a DNS/DHCP server, that is separate from your gateway (and giving out a domain suffix)? ;)

Comment: I'm attempting to upgrade the home version to Win 7 Pro.  But the anytime upgrade doesn't even attempt to make a connection if the Network and Sharing cetner reports no connection.  The DNS/DHCP info is correct.

Comment: How big of a subnet do you need?

Comment: @Luke I'm not sure I understand where you're going with that, can you enlighten me?

Comment: @SouthFresh You have a subnet mask of 255.255.254.0, meaning it can have 510 addresses on the network

Comment: Ahh, sorry.  We have quite a number of end users, network devices, and everyone's cell phone is on our wifi as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this a few times, more usually on Vista; and it's annoying.

The easiest thing I've found that 'fixed it' in many cases (not all) was to merge and erase all the various network entries/profiles (wired and/or wireless), until there were none.

I'm NOT talking about the networking devices/drivers themselves.  Just the various "Home", "Work", and "Public" network entries representing your networks.

Reboot, let it rediscover and reconnect to the network(s) (it should ask you which 'type' again).

Hopefully it will be less confused after that. :)

To do this:

1. Open "Control Panel"
2. Select and open "Network and Sharing Center"
3. Click the "Icon" (like the House icon) under "View your active networks". This will open the "Set Network Properties" dialog. Here you can rename a network connection or change the icon for that network connection.
4. Click "Merge or Delete Network Locations" to see a list of stored network connections. You can merge or delete connections here as well as see if a network connection is in use and managed or unmanaged.

Comment: On Win 7 Home Premium where do I got to modify the network profiles?

Comment: @SouthFresh Updated my answer with some instruction.

Comment: Under "View your active networks" I have: "You are not connected to any networks" And yet I can still post this message from the same computer.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check your network-card drivers.  I've run into this with older-network cards/drivers several times.  More than likely, you need to go to the manufacturer's website to get the correct driver.  Many network adapters will "work" ... but because they don't have the proper bits to tell windows 7/vista that it's indeed an ethernet adapter... they aren't treated like normal ethernet network adapters... and are treated more like a generic network interface that could be virtual or some form of tunneling adapter.

Comment: Installing manufacturer drivers provides no change.

Comment: What is the date on the driver?

Comment: Driver Date = 9/27/11

Comment: any other suggestions?  I'm still stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Scan for viruses and malware. Also check that the Network and Sharing Center service in SERVICES.MSC is set to Automatic Startup, and is running

EDIT: I just checked my Win7 machine, and found these are the Network services. Is this what yours look like?

[image: These are the services that need to be started]

Comment: No viruses or malware detected. I'm not seeing anything with that specific name. Win7 Home Premium (will update question). Do you have another name for it?

Comment: @SouthFresh See updated answer

Comment: All services are started.  I have also previously attempted to stop and restart each of these.  Doing so provides no change in behavior.

Comment: Any other suggestions?  I'm now at the point where I don't care about how fast this is going to get fixed, I just don't want to be beaten by the OS.

Comment: Try `SFC /SCANNOW`?

Comment: Trying, will report back

Answer (score 0):

Does it say no network or no internet?

If it says no network, the other suggested solutions should be tried.

If it says no internet (or limited connectivity) this may simply mean the computer cannot download the text file from Microsoft that it uses to test for internet access. This may occur on company or managed networks and usually simply means that url is blocked.

See "How Does It Work" in the following SU Blog: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/

Comment: "You are not currently connected to any networks"  Except I'm using the system to post this message to you.

Comment: Ok, then my answer is probably of no help.

Answer (score 0):

Please import the registry from working system `HKLM\system\services\netprofm` and overwrite to the faulty system. This problem resolved for me